# How do I process a mouse click using Quartz events?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, cgeventtap

I have a `CGEventTap` and I would like to observe and process all system mouse click events. Detecting a mouse click event is easy, but I don’t want some of the clicks to get processed by the rest of the system. And I can’t figure out how.

The system only sends low-level events like `mouseUp`, `mouseDown`, `mouseDragged` and so on. When I receive a `mouseDown` event, I don’t know if it’s a part of a mouse click yet, could be a drag event. I have to wait for the following event – if it’s a `mouseUp`, I have a click. But if I want to process the click myself and keep it from going down the rest of the event queue, I can’t simply steal the `mouseUp` event, as the previous `mouseDown` was already sent.

I thought I could delay the `mouseDown` event and only send it later after receiving the corresponding `mouseUp`, but that feels wrong, I don’t want to delay all system `mouseDown` events just because of my application. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you think you might be missing something? What makes you think you should be able to do this?

Comment: I thougth that maybe there’s an easier way to monitor and change all system mouse events. I can observe and filter the key events just fine this way, it seems strange that it should be impossible to do the same with a simple mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

What you thought is actually right. You have to postpone mouse down event for the time interval equal to a mouse [double click speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-click#Speed_and_timing), that should be around 100-500 milliseconds. User will not notice a 100 millisecond delay, for example. Ideally, you should a value from Mac OS X [mouse settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2490#l1) to make a good user experience.